# Loop in try catch block

Tags: c#, loops, try-catch

I need a method that will ensure that i'm entering correct types of values AND that will get me to the point where i am supposed to enter them again. I do not need recursion to get to the beginning of the method, I need something to get to the place where I'm entering values. I know I am supposed to use loops, but I do not know how to do that. This is part of the method:

```
console.writeline("Enter your value");
double kv = 0;
try
{
    kv = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
}
```

Comment: Don't use Try..Catch for expected behavior (like entering a string that is not convertible to double).  Use [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Use `Double.TryParse` instead of try/catch:

```
Console.Writeline("Enter your value");
double kv;
while (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out kv))
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
```

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure what you mean; your answer looks identical except you wrap it all up in functions.

Comment: @Servy Yes, sorry I edited 3 times in the span of 10 seconds as I realized I made mistakes. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can follow this particular pattern:

```
var data = GetValueFromUser();
while(!IsValid(data))
{
    InformUserTheirDataIsBad();
    data = GetValueFromUser();
}
//data is now valid
```

Answer (score 2):

Use TryParse

```
        double kv = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your value");
        while (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out kv) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your value");
        }
```

Comment: Why do you use `== false` instead of just prepending a `!` (logical not)?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen  because `!condition` looks more like `condition` than `condition == false` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can se a `do while` loop too:

```
double kv = 0;
bool invalid = false;
do
{
   console.writeline("Enter your value");       
   try
   {
      kv = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
      invalid = false;
   }
   catch (FormatException)
   { invalid = true;}
} while (invalid);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use exceptions for control flow.  Also, this goes into an infinite loop; you never set `invalid` to false.

Comment: I agree with you, I was just showing another way. I think OP is just trying to learn some loops.

Comment: While I don't think you should use `try`-`catch` for this, here's a loop with `try`-`catch` that looks simpler: `double kv;
while (true)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter your value");       
   try
   {
      kv = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
      break;
   }
   catch (FormatException)
   { }
}`